# Referencing FROM subquery in SELECT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `SELECT` query like this:

```
SELECT
    SubQuery.Year            AS Year,
    SubQuery.Customer        AS Customer,
    SUM(SubQuery.OrderCount) AS OrderCount
FROM
    {complexquery} AS SubQuery
GROUP BY
    SubQuery.Year, SubQuery.Customer
```

which gives results like this:

```
+--------+----------+------------+
| year   | customer | ordercount |
+--------+----------+------------+
| 2015   | John     | 10         |
+--------+----------+------------+
| 2015   | Amy      | 20         |
+--------+----------+------------+
| 2015   | Bob      | 10         |
+--------+----------+------------+
| 2014   | John     | 200        |
+--------+----------+------------+
| 2014   | Amy      | 200        |
+--------+----------+------------+
| 2014   | Bob      | 200        |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

And I would like to add the "ratio" column where customer's portion of the whole year ordercount would be displayed, like this:

```
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
| year   | customer | ordercount | ratio |
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
| 2015   | John     | 10         | 0.25  |
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
| 2015   | Amy      | 20         | 0.5   |
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
| 2015   | Bob      | 10         | 0.25  |
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
| 2014   | John     | 200        | 0.33  |
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
| 2014   | Amy      | 200        | 0.33  |
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
| 2014   | Bob      | 200        | 0.33  |
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
```

I tried something like:

```
SELECT
    SubQuery.Year            AS Year,
    SubQuery.Customer        AS Customer,
    SUM(SubQuery.OrderCount) AS OrderCount
    SUM(SubQuery.OrderCount) / (SELECT SUM(OrderCount) FROM SubQuery WHERE...) AS Ratio
FROM
    {complexquery} AS SubQuery
GROUP BY
    SubQuery.Year, SubQuery.Customer
```

But was not successfull - I can not reference `SubQuery` in the `SELECT` clause.

I think there should be some elegant way to solve it but I do not see it.

I do not want to repeat `{complexquery}` in the `SELECT` as the `{complexquery}` is long.

I can not modify database schema.

I am using MS SQL server.

Comment: CTE? (common table expression), perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place your select statement into a further subquery then use a [window function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189461.aspx) to get the grand total and divide by this:

```
WITH Subquery AS
(   SELECT
        SubQuery.[Year]          AS [Year],
        SubQuery.Customer        AS Customer,
        SUM(SubQuery.OrderCount) AS OrderCount
    FROM
        {complexquery} AS SubQuery
    GROUP BY
        SubQuery.[Year], SubQuery.Customer
)
SELECT  [Year],
        Customer,
        OrderCount,
        1.0 * OrderCount / SUM(OrderCount) OVER(PARTITION BY [Year]) AS Ratio
FROM    Subquery;
```

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
DECLARE @ComplexSubquery TABLE ([year] INT, Customer VARCHAR(10), OrderCount INT);

INSERT @ComplexSubquery ([year], Customer, OrderCount)
VALUES
    (2015, 'John', 10),
    (2015, 'Amy', 20),
    (2015, 'Bob', 10),
    (2014, 'John', 200),
    (2014, 'Amy', 200),
    (2014, 'Bob', 200);

WITH Subquery AS
(   SELECT
        SubQuery.[Year]          AS [Year],
        SubQuery.Customer        AS Customer,
        SUM(SubQuery.OrderCount) AS OrderCount
    FROM
        @ComplexSubquery AS SubQuery
    GROUP BY
        SubQuery.[Year], SubQuery.Customer
)
SELECT  [Year],
        Customer,
        OrderCount,
        1.0 * OrderCount / SUM(OrderCount) OVER(PARTITION BY [Year]) AS Ratio
FROM    Subquery;
```

Comment: [Window function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189461.aspx) was what I was looking for. Thank you.